# "A look of disgust" vs "A face of disgust" vs "A disgusted face"

Tags: difference, phrase-usage, phrase-choice, prepositional-phrases

Do you think the phrases, *a look of disgust,* *a face of disgust,* and *a disgusted face* can be used interchangeably? For example, do you think these sentences can be used interchangeably?

> John looked at me with a look of disgust.

> John looked at me with a face of disgust.

> John looked at me with a disgusted face.

I am guessing the first sentence is the most idiomatic one. Do you think they can be used interchangeably?

Comment: This is nothing to do with grammar, so you're really just inviting us to vote in a "popularity contest". But [here's a chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=with+a+look+of+disgust%2Cwith+a+face+of+disgust%2Cwith+a+disgusted+face&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) showing relative prevalence for these three expressions, so effectively ***that vote has already been taken***.

Comment: Except that 'look with a look of' is too repetitive. "Turned to me with a look of disgust" or simply "looked at me with disgust" (if it is the speaker who disgusts John).

Comment: I was agreeing with @FumbleFingers that the first is much the most natural, _except_ that (what I said before).

Comment: I want the topic to be closed because as I said, it's nothing to do with grammar. It's just "writing advice". But for all my degree in English Literature, I didn't even *notice* that your first version is hopelessly clunky simply because of the repetition flagged up by @KateBunting. Which means not only are you presenting us with a "beauty contest" - we even have to include additional "contestants" of our own, because none of yours are good enough to be crowned the winner.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This is a normal question that can be asked by an English learner in my opinion.

Comment: We're all entitled to our opinions here. You've expressed yours by asking, and I've expressed mine by closevoting. It's up to others whether they endorse my VTC enough to actually make it happen - but regardless of that, there's no possibility of anyone posting a single unambiguously ***correct*** answer, so I won't be changing ***my*** opinion that this question is Off Topic Primarily Opinion-Based.

Comment: As commented, none of them, so there cannot be a *most idiomatic* version.

Answer (score 1):

"Look of disgust" is the right phrase, but you would avoid repeating the word "look".  Idiomatic sentences would be

> John gave me a look of disgust.

> John shot me a look of disgust.

> A look of disgust was apparent on John's face

> John's look of disgust told me all I needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

All of the sentences are fundamentally flawed.

If you look at actual sentences identified by [FumbleFingers' NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=with%20a%20look%20of%20disgust%2Cwith%20a%20face%20of%20disgust%2Cwith%20a%20disgusted%20face&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), you will see that we only use "with a look/...face..." to describe somebody's expression when the verb is other than looking. This applies regardless of the particular phrasing, for example

> The redcoat went away with a look of disgust on his face *- The Liberty Boys, Barry Moore 2018*
> “And shut the door behind you,” said Liddell, still with a face of disgust. *- The Cure of Silver Canyon, Max Brand 2018*
> “I did, and I was sick at the sight of it,” said Darius with a disgusted face. *- 13 Kings, VS Nesby, 2019*

That said, there are occasional occurrences of "looked... with a disgusted face", but only in books where the general standard of writing is low, for example the first occurrence of this expression is followed by this sentence:

> Are [sic] tongues danced in a ra-ta-ta rhythm. *- Is this feeling Love? James Rodriguez, 2019*

If the verb is look, or something related to it, we don't need to say 'a look" or "a face"... the prepositional phrase applies directly to the verb, so we can just say "with disgust".

> John looked at me with disgust.